# Looking for a 1-click add a web (or local) file to email solution. Not sure if it exists

Tags: python, php, html, jquery, mysql

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place for this, but I not exactly sure where is the right place to pose this issue.

I'm being asked to make a web page or spread sheet with a table of PDFs and add a button where each PDF can be attached to an email. As in, a one-click solution to add the actual PDF into an email, not a link to the file. I don't think this is possible since the file is hosted on the web... BUT...

If the file is hosted locally on our internal server is there a code or function that would be able to do that?

Basically, the company owner is old and doesn't want to have to search for files to add to emails. He wants to just be able to open a list (web, excel, whatever), click on the one(s) he wants, and have them add to an email. I need to be able to manage and update the PDF files on the back end and update the table.

Of course the easy thing is to have a shared folder, but it lacks organization of an easily readable table. Alternately, he want to attach the actual file, not send a link.

I can't think of a way to do this, but plenty of people are smarter than I.

And advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is far too broad to be on-topic for stack overflow. It seems like something that could be built, but SO is for _specific_ coding and programming questions for which you can provide a [mcve]. Your best bet might be to do some of your own research, try some things, and come back and ask when have a specific issue

Comment: In python you can programmatically download a file easily. Same for attaching a file. None of what you're asking for is difficult or new in Python, it should be really straightforward. Now, I will say that you probably won't get answers here, since you've posted no code, and are essentially just asking for opinions or tips on what to do next, rather than asking anything that objective.